# Fast way to edit nth line of previous command output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, vim

I often find find myself doing a workflow like this:

```
$ find . |grep somefile
./tmp/somefile.xml
./test/another-somefile.txt
```

(review output)

```
$ vim ./tmp/somefile.xml
```

Now, it would be neat if there was some convenient way of using the output of the find command  and feed it to vim.

The best I've come up with is:

```
$ nth () { sed -n $1p; }
$ find . |grep somefile
./tmp/somefile.xml
./test/another-somefile.txt
```

(review output)

```
$ vim `!!|nth 2`
```

I was wondering if there are other, maybe prettier, ways of accomplishing the same thing?

To clarify, I want a convenient way of grabbing the nth line from a previously run command to quickly open that file for editing in vim, without having to cut & paste the filename with the mouse or tab-complete my way through the file path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**way 1: don't pass exact file to vim, but the whole output. choose the file in vim**

currently you are working in two steps:

1 - launch the find/grep... cmd

2 - vim !!....

if you are sure that you want to use vim to open one (or more) file(s) from the find result. you may try:

```
find. (with grep if you like)  |vim -
```

then you have the whole output in vim, now you can use vim magic to move cursor to the file you want to edit, then press `gf`.  (I do this sometimes)

**way 2: refine your regex in your find (or grep), to get the single file, that you want to edit.**

this is not a hard thing at all. then you can just vim `!!`.

your nth() is nice. however imagine there are 30 lines in output, and your file sits in the line# 16. how do you count it? sure you can add `|nl` at the end, then you cannot directly use !! any longer..

just my 2 cents

Comment: I think piping the command to `vim -` and then using `gf` is the solution that I would feel most comfortable with. However my vim requires me to save the file list buffer before allowing me to do `gf`. Is there a way to make vim treat buffers from stdin as temporary/hidden buffers?

Comment: Adding `set hidden` to ~/.vimrc seems to do the trick. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Erik I edited your question, for adding a new tag "vim". hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Modified after your comment. Not sure if it's "convenient" though..

```
command | tail -n3 | head -n1 | xargs vim
```

Comment: No, I want a convenient way to grab the nth line from the output of a previous command and feed it as an argument to vim.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
find . -name "*somefile*" -exec vim -p {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an interactive review maybe you can use something like this:

```
TMP_LIST=""; for i in `find . | grep somefile`; do echo $i; read -p "(y/n)?"; [ $REPLY == "y" ] && TMP_LIST="$TMP_LIST $i"; done; vim $TMP_LIST
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, but not what I'm looking for. The point is that my workflow is 1) find/ls/..., 2) see a file i want to edit, 3) quickly open that file in vim without mouse cut&paste of filename or tab-completing the path

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it!!

```
pearl.251> cat file1
a b c d e f pearl.252> find . -name "file*"
./file1
./file2
./file3
./file4
./file5
./file6
./file7
pearl.253> vi `!!|awk 'NR==1'`
```

the last line overe here will open the file1 in `vi`.